# Outer in R not working

Tags: r

Here is a toy example of where I'm trying to use outer but it is not working.

```
A=matrix(1:4,2,2)
B=matrix(1:8,2,4)
g=function(i,j) as.vector(t(A[i,]-B[i,c(j,2+j)])%*%(A[i,]-B[i,c(j,2+j)]))
g(1,2)
[1] 20
g(1,1)
[1] 4
g(2,1)
[1] 4
g(2,2)
[1] 20
outer(1:2,1:2,g)
Error in A[i, ] - B[i, c(j, 2 + j)] : non-conformable arrays
```

In my actual data both A and B have really large dimensions so using for loop or mapply is very slow. Is there any way to use outer to obtain the result ?

Comment: The first line of the Details section of `?outer` states: "X and Y must be suitable arguments for FUN.". Run `g(1:2,1:2)`.

Comment: g(1:2,1:2) gives the same error

Comment: .........exactly! If your function `g` doesn't work with those inputs, it will never work with `outer`.

Comment: `outer` is just going to call `g(c(1,1,2,2),c(1,2,1,2))`. Your function isn't vectorized in a manner that handles that.

Comment: Thanks Joran that helps ... I'll try to modify it ...

Comment: Yes Vectorizing the function works .. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can write a helper function to deliver the values from an `mapply` implementation using `expand.grid`'s capacity for enumeration all teh n x m combinations:

```
> gh=function(df) mapply( g, df[,1], df[,2])
> gh(expand.grid(1:2,1:2))
[1]  4  4 20 20
```

The ordering will be all rows in first column, then all rows in second column, then ....